# passing data from parent to child angular 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, binding

I have some general questions, I start of on page `main.ts`
Via `onInit` I am grabbing data from a mongoose database server, which I save in an array.

This array needs to be available in other components. The way I do this right now, which seems to work, by using a `service.ts`

In the service I have a lot `BehaviorSubjects` and `Subjects`. So whenever I get the array data from mongoose I send a message to the service, and the other components subscribe to that message.

I am sometimes using `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` because it throws error messages as in HTML I am using `*ngFor` and it expects an array, not a string 'default message'.

I am just wondering if this is a correct setup to move data between pages.
Right now I am also using this message system for updates on my component. 
So if someone makes a comment or post on my website I send a message to my service which in turn updates an observable and my component subscribes again to that.

Are there better ways to update my site for new data and is there an easy way to explain why sometimes I get this error message from `*ngFor` and in other cases it doesn't throw this error whilst still using `*ngFor`.

i.e. when I update an observable will the component receive the message straight away or will it receive onInit.

With that also the question if it is best practice to use the below in the constructor of the component or the `onInit`. 
I unsubscribe `OnDestroy`.

```
this.newService.currentMessageComment
  .takeWhile(() => this.alive)

   .subscribe(message => {
```

service.ts

```
public messageSourceMarketCap = new BehaviorSubject<any>('default message');
currentMessageMarketCap = this.messageSourceMarketCap.asObservable();

public messageSourceHistory = new Subject<any>();
currentMessageHistory = this.messageSourceHistory.asObservable();

public messageSouceApi = new BehaviorSubject<any>('default message');
currentMessageApi = this.messageSouceApi.asObservable();

public messageSourceBody = new BehaviorSubject<any>('default message');
currentMessageBody = this.messageSourceBody.asObservable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using BehaviouSubject. I think in your case Subject will be better. BehaviouSubject fits in case when you want to pass a initial value while creating observable.

You can also quick fix by emiting an empty array as ngFor expects an array. Change from "default message" to [].

Hope it will help

Comment: So right now I have multiple messages that I subscribe to in a component, is that the correct way of doing it, or is it normal to reuse the message system. Or do I only reuse the message system if updating the same variable?

Comment: Reuseability is better option but it depends on your use case. Always write programs to keep in mind that will it be maintainable if a new feature will introduce in your message system.